# How to get "rendered" image with glReadPixels from FrameBuffer after calling glDrawElements

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es

I modified brightness, contrast, and saturation of some image by fragment shader of OpenGL ES 2.0. And... to save modified image, I used this method.

```
public static Bitmap saveTexture(int texture, int width, int height) {
    int[] frame = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, frame, 0);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frame[0]);
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(width * height * 4);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glDeleteFramebuffers(1, frame, 0);

    return bitmap;
}
```

But, this method return the original image, not modified. What is wrong?
Please advise me how to resolve this. :/

---

I added more information.
This code is my GLSurfaceView.Renderer's code.

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
    mTextureID = OpenGLTools.loadImageTexture(mBitmap, true);
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    mProgram = OpenGLTools.loadProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    draw();
}

public void draw() {
    if (!GLES20.glIsProgram(mProgram)) OpenGLTools.loadProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    int positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "position");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mVertexBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

    int textureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "inputTextureCoordinate");
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordinateHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, mTexCoordBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordinateHandle);

    int brightness = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "brightness");
    GLES20.glUniform1f(brightness, mEditParams.mBrightness / 200.0f);
    int contrast = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "contrast");
    GLES20.glUniform1f(contrast, mEditParams.mContrast / 200.0f);
    int saturation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "saturation");
    GLES20.glUniform1f(saturation, (mEditParams.mSaturation + 100) / 100.0f);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mDrawListBuffer);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordinateHandle);
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return OpenGLTools.saveTexture(mTextureID, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight());
}
```

And... this is the code in OpenGLTools class.

```
public static int loadImageTexture(final Bitmap bitmap, final boolean recycle) {
    int[] textureNames = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureNames, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureNames[0]);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    if (recycle) {
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    return textureNames[0];
}

public static int loadProgram(final String vsc, final String fsc) {
    int[] success = new int[1];

    int vshader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(vshader, vsc);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(vshader);
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(vshader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, success, 0);

    if (success[0] == 0) {
        Log.e("CheckLog", "Could not compile vertex shader : " + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vshader));
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(vshader);
        return 0;
    }

    int fshader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fshader, fsc);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fshader);
    GLES20.glGetShaderiv(fshader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, success, 0);
    if (success[0] == 0) {
        Log.e("CheckLog", "Could not compile fragment shader : " + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(fshader));
        GLES20.glDeleteShader(fshader);
        return 0;
    }

    int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vshader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fshader);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
    GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, success, 0);
    if (success[0] <= 0) {
        Log.e("CheckLog", "Could not link OpenGLES program :" + GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
        GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
        return 0;
    } else {
        Log.i("CheckLog", "Linked OpenGLES program");
    }

    return program;
}

public static Bitmap saveTexture(int texture, int width, int height) {
    int[] frame = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, frame, 0);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frame[0]);
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(width * height * 4);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glDeleteFramebuffers(1, frame, 0);

    return bitmap;
}
```

If I touch save button, `getBitmap` method is called in the OpenGLES context. I can change the `Bitmap`'s parameters(brightness, contrast and saturation) and it shows up on display in real time. However, changed parameters are not applied the saved image when I touch the save button. I want to save the image with changed parameters.

Comment: Can you post some relevant code? If you are getting something saved at all then the above code works, you're just feeding it the wrong input, so the error isn't in the code above.

Comment: I added relevant code. Check it please.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the original texture handle as the `texture` parameter input into `saveTexture()`, so it's no surprise that that is the data you are saving back to disk.

You don't actually want to save a texture - you want to save the contents of the active framebuffer - so that function isn't what your code needs. Try this one:

```
public static Bitmap saveTexture(int width, int height) {   
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(width * height * 4);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);      
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Your code works well. However there is another problem. It is that the image from active frame buffer is located at the corner of the whole black image as small resolution because the default frame buffer(active frame buffer) is not larger than display resolution. So, I think I need to know how to render the result image to large frame buffer instead of default frame buffer. If you know it, please tell me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you need to render something larger than the screen you need to render to an off-screen framebuffer.