# Get pixels from GLSurfaceView on background thread

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I am using the [HelloAR demo application](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/tutorials/hello-ar-sample) and I want to capture the screen of my Samsung Galaxy Tab S5e.

In `onDrawFrame` I call my screenshot function:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Capture the screen
    createBitmapFromGLSurface(gl);
    ....
}
```

Here is the `createBitmapFromGLSurface` function:

```
public void createBitmapFromGLSurface(GL10 gl) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(w * h * 4);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

    //Do something with the bitmap
}
```

This works (image gets saved to disk and is perfect), but it is absolutely dog slow! So, I thought to offload it to a background thread... and tried to wrap it in an AsyncTask:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           createBitmapFromGLSurface(gl);
        }
}
```

However, this just gives me a totally blank (transparent) image when I save the bitmap to disk.

How can I speed this up, get it to work on a background thread or (preferably) both?

Comment: Shouldn't need to do the loops like that, maybe this is much faster; https://stackoverflow.com/a/41565948/360211

Comment: @weston Well, thanks, that makes the code a lot more simple and easier to read, but it doesn't really make much difference to performance. I haven't measured, but its still dog slow.

Comment: Are you really doing on every onDrawFrame call? What is the actual goal here?

Comment: @weston Yes, every frame (for now). I want to pipe the frames to disk as images, not video.

Comment: You will never achieve writing 60 fps to disk, either on main thread or utilizing other threads. But it doesn't sound like your end goal anyway because of "for now", so suggest you skip this milestone.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL stuff runs on its own dedicated thread, which has a GL context - you're probably getting a blank screen because it's running on another thread, without access to that context?

weston's version runs on the same thread, which should be why it works! But you're doing a bunch of allocations (and IO if you're writing the bitmap out) which you really want to avoid in `onDrawFrame`. You have 16ms to get everything done to maintain a smooth 60fps. Is that what you mean by slow, the display chugs?

Personally I'd do as little as possible on the GL thread - write the data to the buffer, then hand that buffer off to a worker thread to create a bitmap, write to disk etc. Ideally allocate the buffer once and reuse it (but you'll have to manage concurrency, so you're not writing to your buffer on one thread while another thread is trying to read it).

I wouldn't use an `AsyncTask` personally but it should still work - you're only meant to call `#execute` [from the UI thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#execute(Params...)) though, so if you're messing around with Loopers that might slow it down a bit too.